# C++ Non overloadable function

Tags: c++, overloading

Please I would like to know if there is a way to make a function non overloadable.
My idea is to keep it private in the class so that it will be impossible to overload the function in a derived class.

But if in the base class (the one that holds the private function) I also have a public or protected function (let's call it plf) to manage the private one (let's call it prf), and in the derived class I create a function with the same name as the private base class function (prf) that calls for the public base class function (plf), **I am wondering if there won't be a conflict between both of the same-named (prf) functions?**

Assuming the prf function of the derived class is not an overload of the prf function of the base class (because the last one is not visible).

Thanks in advance.

I just did the following test:

```
class a
{
private:
    void x();
public:
    void y();
    a();
};

class b : public a
{
public:
    void x();
    b();
};

a::a(){}

void a::x()
{
    cout << "Write a" << endl;
}

void a::y()
{
    x();
}

b::b(){}

void b::x()
{
    y();
}

int main()
{
    b t;
    t.x();
    return 0;
}
```

This returns a's x() without any conflict.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show a code example of what you are asking.

Comment: Overload or override? To prohibit overriding, C++11 introduced the `final` "keyword".

Comment: `Please I would like to know if there is a way to make a function non overloadable.` There's not.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using `private` access to prevent *overloading* is valid and works.

But

- it does not prevent *overriding* of a virtual function, and
- due to the way that C++ name lookup works, it's unnecessary.

---

It's unnecessary because a member function declaration of the same name in a derived class, **shadows** the declaration in the base class, just as a name declared in some inner scope shadows any declaration of that name in an outer scope.

There is, by default, no overloading of base class names in a derived class.

The derived class can use `using` declarations to bring in the base class definitions as overloads, but then it's done purposefully, with the programmer's intention and knowledge. This very explicit and intentional kind of overloading is the kind that's prevented by having the base class member function private, because then it can't be subject of `using` in a derived class. But as I see it, while preventing unintentional overloading could have some merit, preventing intentional explicit overloading does not appear to be meaningful.

---

To prevent overriding of a member function you can

- use C++11 `final`, or
- have some formal argument of a private type.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware of the final keyword in C++ but only in Java. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: `have some formal argument of a private type.` - What does it mean?

Comment: @ikh: a *private type* is a type define after a `private:` access specifier, before any other access specifier. for example, it can be an `enum` type. a *formal argument* is an argument declared in a functions head.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Um? Can the parameter of `public`/`protected` member functions have `private` type?

Comment: @ikh: yes, a public or protected member function can have a formal argument of private type, but for public or protected member function that's only meaningful if the argument has a default. so here there's a difference between technically correct at the code level, and meaningful at the design level. just provide a default an you're okay.